# Display user's photoURL

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am new to Firebase (web) and trying to display the user's photoURL in the view on an img tag. Something like:

What is the JavaScript to get element by id and change the src attribute?

I'm using the basic example found here:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web#using-firebaseui-for-authentication

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You must add a new depedencie to you Build.Gradle (App Level) File :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Than Create an ImageView.
You can now set the src of the ImageView with the FirebaseUsers PhotoURL:

```
ImageView iw = find.....

Glide.with(this).load(*).centerCrop().override(512, 512).into(iw);

* Can you replace with the current User (z.B : mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString() )
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('imgId').src= firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL;
```